# Custom attributes not showing in Active Model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I am getting incomplete fields for my serializers custom records when they include custom fields:

Category Serializer:

```
class CategorySerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :name, :localized_name, :picture, :status, :visible, :country

def localized_name
  I18n.t((object.name + '_name').to_sym)
end

end
```

Match Serializer:

```
class MatchSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :player1, :player2, :match_type, :status, :winner, :score, :match_categories

  def match_categories
    #adds international category array to the intersection of player1 and player2 category arrays
    #this is done so that players playing against other countries player will allways
    #play at least international categories and any other categories common to both

    Category.where(country_id: 1) +
(Category.where(country_id: object.player1.country) & Category.where(country_id: object.player2.country))
  end

end
```

When rendering the category, I get the complete fields as a JSON response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "categories",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Sports",
        "localized_name": "Deportes",
        "picture": "default_url",
        "status": "active",
        "visible": false,
        "country": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "International",
          "country_code": "NA",
          "picture": "default_url",
          "language_code": "en",
          "status": "active",
          "visible": false,
          "created_at": "2016-06-06T16:12:29.701Z",
          "updated_at": "2016-06-06T16:12:29.701Z"
        }
      }
    },
```

When rendering a match, the Match serializer will calculate an array of categories involved in the match and render Category information for each. However, as you can see, the category custom field: `localized_name` is not included.

```
>{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "matches",
      "attributes": {
        "player1": {
          "id": 1,
          "provider": "email",
          "uid": "user1@gmail.com",
          "country_id": 2,
          "name": null,
          "first_name": null,
          "last_name": null,
          "gender": null,
          "fb_auth_token": null,
          "nickname": null,
          "image": null,
          "email": "user1@gmail.com",
          "friend_count": null,
          "friends": null,
          "status": "active",
          "premium": null,
          "created_at": "2016-06-06T16:13:58.711Z",
          "updated_at": "2016-06-06T16:14:15.722Z"
        },
        "player2": {
          "id": 2,
          "provider": "email",
          "uid": "user2@gmail.com",
          "country_id": 2,
          "name": null,
          "first_name": null,
          "last_name": null,
          "gender": null,
          "fb_auth_token": null,
          "nickname": null,
          "image": null,
          "email": "user2@gmail.com",
          "friend_count": null,
          "friends": null,
          "status": "active",
          "premium": null,
          "created_at": "2016-06-07T08:03:38.472Z",
          "updated_at": "2016-06-07T08:03:38.611Z"
        },
        "match_type": "Duel",
        "status": "active",
        "winner": null,
        "score": null,
        **"match_categories": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "country_id": 1,
            "name": "Sports",
            "picture": "default_url",
            "status": "active",
            "visible": false,
            "created_at": "2016-06-06T16:12:29.893Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-06-06T16:12:29.893Z"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "country_id": 2,
            "name": "Futbolistas Peruanos",
            "picture": "default_url",
            "status": "active",
            "visible": false,
            "created_at": "2016-06-06T16:12:29.961Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-06-06T16:12:29.961Z"
          },
```

How can I get the localized_name field to display in this scenario?

EDIT: Requested controllers. Pretty standard

```
class MatchesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_match, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

 # GET /matches
  def index
    @matches = Match.all

    render json: @matches
  end

  # GET /matches/1
  def show
    render json: @match
  end

  # POST /matches
  def create
    @match = Match.new(match_params)

    #if player1 not explicitly included will set player1 as uid header of API call
    @match.player1_id ||= current_user.id
    #if player2 parame set as random will generate random user from all curently active users
    if params[:match][:player2_id] == 'random'
      #call model method that returns a random array of userids to play as player 2 but
      #passing player1_id so that method will remove it from possible responses
      #since player1 cannot play itself
      @match.player2_id = @match.active_random_player2(@match.player1_id)
    end

    if @match.save
      render json: @match, status: :created, location: @match
    else
      render json: @match.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /matches/1
  def update
    if @match.update(match_params)

      render json: @match
    else
      render json: @match.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /matches/1
  def destroy
    @match.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_match
      @match = Match.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def match_params
  params.require(:match).permit(:player1_id, :player2_id, :match_type, :bet, :status, :winner, :score)
    end
end


class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /categories/newmatch
  def newmatch
    @categories = Category.where(country: current_user.country)

    render json: @categories
  end

  # GET /categories
  def index
    if params[:all] && params[:all] != 'false'
      @categories = Category.all
    else
      @categories = Category.where(country: current_user.country)
    end

    render json: @categories

  end

  # GET /categories/1
  def show
    render json: @category
  end

  # POST /categories
  def create

    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    if @category.save!
      render json: @category, status: :created, location: @category
    else
      render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /categories/1
  def update
    if @category.update(category_params)
      render json: @category
    else
      render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /categories/1
  def destroy
    @category.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def category_params
      #add permitted translation locale parameters based on required translations
      #resource agnostic method in application controller
      params.require(:category).permit(:name, :picture, :status, :visible, :country_id, :all)
    end
end
```

Edit:

when trying Francesco Lupo's suggestion I get this information in the match_categories query field, but I'm still not getting the custom localized_name field.

```
"match_categories": [
          {
            "object": {
              "id": 1,
              "country_id": 1,
              "name": "Sports",
              "picture": "default_url",
              "status": "active",
              "visible": false,
              "created_at": "2016-07-08T23:11:43.304Z",
              "updated_at": "2016-07-08T23:11:43.304Z"
            },
            "instance_options": {
              "root": false
            },
            "root": false,
            "scope": null
          },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to serialize each of your categories, querying is not enough, maybe try this:

```
def match_categories
  categories = Category.where(country_id: 1) + (Category.where(country_id: object.player1.country) & Category.where(country_id: object.player2.country))
  categories.map { |category| CategorySerializer.new(category, root: false) }
end
```

This way all of your categories will be serialized properly.

According to @Augusto comment, maybe an update of `active_model_serializer` is required.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for trying to help, but this doesn't work either. I have added an edit showing what I get using your suggestion

Comment: I upgraded to latest version of active_model_serializer today (0.10.2) and your answer now works! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing some custom methods vs. using a relationship to the object, you may need to use the CategorySerializer in your method:

```
def match_categories
   categories = Category.where(country_id: 1) + (Category.where(country_id: object.player1.country) & Category.where(country_id: object.player2.country))
   CategorySerializer.new(categories)
end
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it outputs the exact same thing. Still no custom localized_name field when rendering matches.

Comment: Can you post your controller?

Comment: after upgrading ams to (0.10.2) this answer almost works, but gives an error due to the fact that my query returns an array. The answer by Francesco Lupo takes this into account (hence the map function). Thanks for helping out anyway, and the answer is certainly valid for other use cases.